# I want to consolidate particular columns with name from multiple excel file to one sheet

Tags: excel

I want to consolidate particular columns with name from multiple excel file to one sheet. Can anyone help on this. I tried but am not getting what i need

Comment: Try : `Data > Get External Data .. ` | btw in your tries.. which part is working, which part is not.. ?

Comment: Please refer to the following page on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also provide the code/formula you are using along with data, the results you are getting and also the expected results.